# XPath suggestion needed to select text

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath

I have a html document with following html code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>page XYZ</title>
</head>

<body>
<p><b>bold text</b> some more text </p>
    
    <p><b>1.</b>&nbsp;hello<br><b>2.</b>&nbsp;how<br><b>3.</b>&nbsp;do you do?</p><p>some more text in a paragraph.</p>   
    </body>
</html>
```

I need to write XPath to print 3 points with their text, i.e.,

```
1. hello
2. how
3. do you do?
```

so far I have tried this: (but it is not printing text)

```
    List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//p/following-sibling::p/b"));

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

        WebElement el = list.get(i);
        String text = el.getText();
        System.out.println(text);
}
```

Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select text only you should use `//p[2]/text()`
and if you need to print 1. 2. 3. you should use `p[2]/b`

if you need to select both you should use
`//p[2]` as string without `.findElements()` then in your code split it to be like a list

Comment: //p[2] worked (so I am accepting your answer), but again in Selenium, using text() function in XPath expression would throw an error as invalid selector.

Answer (score 1):

Use the xpath `"(//p[2])/text()"`which will return the text inside the sibling `<p>` tag. Use the xpath `"(//p[2])/b"` to fetch the numbers 1,2,3 in bold.

To get the desired output, you can try the following:

```
List<WebElement> numberList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//p[2])/b"));
List<WebElement> textList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//p[2])/text()"));

for(int i = 0; i < textList.size() && i < numberList.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(numberList.get(i).getText() + " " + textList.get(i).getText());
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply. XPath expression "(//p[2])/text()" is working fine as XPath only but in Selenium it is throwing error as: InvalidSelectorError.